# Remove Visual studio 2015 product key PC to be applied on another?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on my PC but need to remove it's product key and apply it on another (work) computer. I thought my MSDN account provided multiple installations and as I found out, it doesn't. BTW, I'm using Windows 7.

Have anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you back up your project and then uninstall Visual Studio, it takes that key off that computer as it's no longer installed, therefor it wouldn't be attached. So i believe it's as simple as:

1. Backup your projects.
2. Uninstall Visual Studio From That PC.
3. Install Visual Studio Into The New Computer.
4. Copy your projects to your new computer.
5. Install the key into the newly installed Visual Studio

I hope this helps!

Comment: I uninstalled Visual Studio and tried the product key but no luck. Don't know if the problem is that the other machine have Visual Studio with trial version expired already installed.